# Number of permutations with all cycles of even length

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

For even $n$ (only!), let $e_n$ stand for the number of permutations with all cycle of even length. Let $E(x)$ be the exponential generating functions. Prove that $E(x) = (1 - x^2)^{-\frac12}.$

I tried to find the generating function as a formal sum, but it didn't work out.

Comment: Is that $-\frac12$ supposed to be an exponent?

Comment: @jmerry, yes it is.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316580900126 : Abstract

We give a direct count of the number of permutations of n objects for which (a) all the cycles have lengths divisible by a fixed integer d, and (b) none of the cycles has length divisible by d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The egf for the number of ways to put $n$ elements into an even length cycle is
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n-1)!\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}
&=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^6}{6}+\dots
\\&=\frac12(-\log(1-x)-\log(1+x))
\\&=\log\big((1-x^2)^{-1/2}\big).
\end{align}
The second equality follows from $\log(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3/3-x^4/4+\dots$

A permutation with only even cycles is formed by partitioning $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ into disjoint nonempty components and turning each part into an even length cycle. Therefore, by the exponential formula, the egf for even cycle only permutations is
$$
\exp\log\big((1-x^2)^{-1/2}\big)=(1-x^2)^{-1/2}
$$

Answer (score 3):

We attempt to find a recurrence relation for the $e_n$, and convert that to information about the exponential generating function $E(x)=\sum_n e_n\frac{x^n}{n!}$.

Sort the permutations of $n$ with all cycles of even length by the length of the cycle that includes $1$. If this cycle has length $2k$, then there are $\binom{n-1}{2k-1}$ ways to choose the other $2k-1$ elements in the cycle, $(2k-1)!$ different cycles on those $2k$ elements, and $e_{n-2k}$ permutations of the $n-2k$ elements outside that cycle with all cycles of even length. Therefore,
$$e_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n-1}{2k-1}\cdot (2k-1)!\cdot e_{n-2k} = \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-2k)!}\cdot e_{n-2k}$$
$$n\frac{e_n}{n!} =\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac{e_{n-2k}}{(n-2k)!}$$
Now, multiply by powers of $x$ to convert that to a generating function. We have that $xE'(x)=\sum_n ne_n\frac{x^n\cdot x}{n!}$, so
\begin{align*}n\frac{e_n}{n!}x^n &= \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac{e_{n-2k}x^{n-2k}}{(n-2k)!}\cdot x^{2k}\\
xE'(x) &= E(x)\cdot (x^2+x^4+\cdots) = \frac{x^2}{1-x^2}E(x)\\
\frac{E'(x)}{E(x)} &= \frac{x}{1-x^2}\\
\ln(E(x)) &= \int \frac{x}{1-x^2}\,dx = C-\frac12\ln(1-x^2)\\
E(x) &= A(1-x^2)^{-\frac12}\end{align*}
We can lock down the constant of integration by evaluating at $x=0$; $e_0=1$, so $E(0)=1$ and $A=1$. There it is.

Answer (score 2):

We want to enumerate $\,e_n,\,$ the number of permutations in $\,S_n\,$
with all cycles of even length. We note that in such a case, $\,n\,$
must be even also since the it is the sum of the length of all of the cycles.
One idea comes from [OEIS sequence A001818](https://oeis.org/A001818)
which is the number of permutations in $\,S_{2n}\,$ with all cycles of
even length **and** also permutations with all cycles of odd length. Note that
[OEIS sequence A177145](http://oeis.org/A177145) is our sequence $\,e_n\,$ **except** its offset is $1$ instead of $0$.

**Every** permutation in $\,S_n\,$ uniquely determines a bi-partition
into elements that belong to even length cycles and those that
belong to odd length cycles. The e.g.f. is $\,(1-x)^{-1/2}(1+x)^{-1/2}\,$
for even length cycles and $\,(1-x)^{-1/2}(1+x)^{1/2}\,$ for the rest. Their product is
$\,(1-x)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n!\, x^n/n!\,$ which is the e.g.f. of $\,n!,\,$ the number of all permutations in $\,S_n\,$ as it should be.

Now apply this to the case of permutations in $\,S_{2n}.\,$ Again, each
such permutation uniquely determines a bi-partition of its elements into even and
odd cycles. We assume that the e.g.f. of permutations in $\,S_{2n}\,$
with all cycles of even length is $\,f(x)\,$ and also those of all odd length.
Their product is $\,f(x)^2\,$ which must equal $\,(1-x^2)^{-1}\,$ which
is the e.g.f. of the number of all permutations in $\,S_{2n}.\,$
This implies that
$\,f(x) = (1-x^2)^{-1/2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \,(2n-1)!!^2\, x^{2n}/(2n)!\,$
as requested.

One proof that $\,f(x)\,$ is also the e.g.f. of permutations with all
cycles of odd length is combinatorial. Given a permutation in $\,S_n\,$ pick
any element $\,t\,$ which is  a fixed point or not. If it is, then the rest of the elements form a permutation with all cycles of odd length as before.
If $\,t\,$ is not a fixed point, then it is mapped to a second element and mapped from a third element. If these two other elements are removed, the remaining permutation has all cycles of odd length as before.